# Spring Boot 2.1.3 an issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, sbt

Hope you are all doing good and great.

1) i am using sbt build tool for java application
2) used java 8
3) spring core - 5.1.5
4) spring boot - 2.1.3

Detailed instructions could be seen from `build.sbt` file
I am not sure why this is failing to start the spring boot engine.
Here i have error log and build file for your reference

Kindly address please

```
    name := "ScalaApp2"

    version := "1.0"

    scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

    val sparkVersion = "2.4.0"
    val springBootVersion = "2.1.3.RELEASE"
    val springCoreVersion = "5.1.5.RELEASE"

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582567/sbt-proxy-configuration- 
     problems
    //https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3645
    // set java home, sbt home

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
      "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % springCoreVersion,
      "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-parent" % springBootVersion,
       "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-web" % springBootVersion,
       "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" % springBootVersion,
       "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-actuator" % springBootVersion,
  "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-security" % springBootVersion,
  "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-test" % springBootVersion
 // "ch.qos.logback " % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
)
// https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html
excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic")
)
```

## ERROR

```
.....
.....
C:\Users\ee210901\.ivy2\cache\org.yaml\snakeyaml\bundles\snakeyaml-1.23.jar" com.java.narayana.SpringBootApp
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

    Mar 07, 2019 3:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
    Mar 07, 2019 3:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
    Mar 07, 2019 3:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;D:\sbt-1.2.8\bin;C:\Users\ee210901\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
    Mar 07, 2019 3:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    Mar 07, 2019 3:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
    Mar 07, 2019 3:00:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig release
    SEVERE: Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4548)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5366)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:990)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:465)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.java.narayana.SpringBootApp.main(SpringBootApp.java:17)


    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an issue with google gson library.
I fixed in sbt file and now spring boot started successfully

Comment: What did you fix exactly? I'm experiencing the same problem now.

Comment: Please mention what was the fix and how you figured it out,Thanks in Advance!